# Function split() is deprecated , preg_split(): No ending delimiter ',' found

Tags: php, split, delimiter, preg-split

I have a PHP script written 10 years ago. Now we moved the script to new server and it's not working. The line that has problem is:

```
$p_industry = split(',', $member['p_industry']);
```

The testing email receive this error message:

> Function split() is deprecated .

I researched this website and then I replaced the script with

```
$p_industry = preg_split(',', $member['p_industry']);
```

Then the testing email receive this different error message:

> preg_split(): No ending delimiter ',' found

When I change script to

```
$p_industry = explode(',', $member['p_industry']);
```

I did not receive any email for error message. But the script seems not working either. It seems not working in a way that it doesn't even send error message to testing email.

What should I change to the script? Can you give me specific answer?

Comment: what's the content of `$member['p_industry']`?

Answer (score 18):

`Preg_*` functions has to have delimiters around pattern. I use `~`.

```
$p_industry = preg_split('~,~', $member['p_industry']);
```

Comment: what `~` is doing here? can u please explain?

Comment: @Dev: `preg_*` functions have delimiters around pattern. That's the main task in this question. https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. Or see https://regex101.com, the regex input, there is full syntax too... `DELIM--regex--DELIM--FLAGS`, eg. `~regex~i`, or `#regex#m`, etc.